# Some websites cannot be reached

Tags: networking, browser

I am using Firefox and Ubuntu 20.04 (recently updated to 22.04). In both versions, some websites cannot be reached through Firefox.

What I have tried:

- changing `resolv.conf`, adding `nameserver 8.8.8.8, nameserver 8.8.4.4`
- trying with chrome (same error)
- clearing every sort of temporary file in Firefox
- disabling every proxy in Firefox

I still can't access e.g. scribd.com. My machine is in dual boot Windows 10/Ubuntu: on Windows, everything works fine.
Do you have any hint?

Comment: First of all I would go to command line and try to ping this URL. Like ping www.example.com and ping -6 www.example.com. Does the ping get a response?

Comment: @ThomasAichinger ping -6 doesn't, whereas ping does

Comment: Can you reach these websites with Chrome or Opera?

Comment: @ThomasAichinger No, at least not with chrome

Comment: Then I would assume this website is down.

Comment: @ThomasAichinger I can reach any website from windows 10 installed on the same computer, in dual boot

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139764/discussion-between-thomas-aichinger-and-leonardo).